# Batch Generate Previews are too dark – how to adjust (Blender 2.82)?

Tags: rendering

Batch Generate Previews are too dark . I tried to adjust lightning (types, power) but it  didn’t work.

How is it to adjust (render engine / setting, light parameters)?

I assume for Batch Generate Previews the settings inside the blend file with objects I want to preview are relevent and not the setting of the current open file where I start the batch operation, or?

Comment: As far as I know previews are generated using world shader settings

Comment: I changed worlds shader (color more white; emissive more white) so that usual render is lighter but nothing changed in previews after render them again